# getStructureId returns the real ID minus 1?

Tags: liferay-6, assets

this is the code I am using :

```
JournalArticle article = null;
article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(classPk);
String structureId = article.getStructureId();
```

When I debugged I found that structureId  is always the real structureId  but minus 1 !!!
Why ?? I need to know if it's Liferay bug ...

thank you,
I am Liferay 6.2 ce ga2.

Answer (score 2):

JournalArticle's field `structureId` is equivalent not to `DDMStructure.structureId`, but to `DDMStructure.structureKey`. I admit, that can be really confusing.

This is due to the DDMStructure's object generation mechanism. When you add new structure using Control Panel, the `structureKey` is generated automatically using *counterLocalService* (check [this](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/dynamicdatamapping/service/impl/DDMStructureLocalServiceImpl.java#L141-L143) code). As it happens just before the [structureId is generated](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/dynamicdatamapping/service/impl/DDMStructureLocalServiceImpl.java#L160), it is always smaller by one.

Answer (score 0):

See following Jira tickets, where it is explained the structureId vs structureKey issue:
  - https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-50671
  - https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-31163